Serve static files within GO using CHI Router
I'm using GO Web-App with CHI Router, but I'm unable to serve static files. This is my File Structure:
- cmd
 - main.go
 - assets
  - style.css
 - views
  - someView.templ

Now I want to serve all files within "assets" directory. But always get a 404 Not Found.
My very simple main.go:
func main() {

    router := chi.NewRouter()

    router.Get("/", indexHandler)
    router.Get("/showExternalProfile", showExternalProfileHandler)

    router.Post("/project_request", projectRequestHandler)
    router.Post("/downloadExternalProfile", downloadExternalProfileHandler)
    router.Post("/aigenerateProfile", aibeautifyHandler)
    router.Post("/project_clear", clearHandler)

    router.Handle("/assets/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}

Already tried different stuff, like "./assets" or "assets" in http.dir or /assets/* and /assets/ within Handle.
Does anyone have an idea?

You're missing a StripPrefix wrapper. See the example in the docs.

The chi repo has an example for this in the repo, you can find it here.
To apply it you your code, it would look like this
func main() {

    router := chi.NewRouter()

    router.Get("/", indexHandler)
    router.Get("/showExternalProfile", showExternalProfileHandler)

    router.Post("/project_request", projectRequestHandler)
    router.Post("/downloadExternalProfile", downloadExternalProfileHandler)
    router.Post("/aigenerateProfile", aibeautifyHandler)
    router.Post("/project_clear", clearHandler)


    // Create a route along /assets that will serve contents from
    // the ./assets/ folder.
    workDir, _ := os.Getwd()
    filesDir := http.Dir(filepath.Join(workDir, "assets"))
    FileServer(router, "/assets", filesDir)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}

// FileServer conveniently sets up a http.FileServer handler to serve
// static files from a http.FileSystem.
func FileServer(r chi.Router, path string, root http.FileSystem) {
    if strings.ContainsAny(path, "{}*") {
        panic("FileServer does not permit any URL parameters.")
    }

    if path != "/" && path[len(path)-1] != '/' {
        r.Get(path, http.RedirectHandler(path+"/", 301).ServeHTTP)
        path += "/"
    }
    path += "*"

    r.Get(path, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rctx := chi.RouteContext(r.Context())
        pathPrefix := strings.TrimSuffix(rctx.RoutePattern(), "/*")
        fs := http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix, http.FileServer(root))
        fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

As a personal opinion, if you are using any additional web servers such as nginx or apache, I would instead recommend to let them handle serving the static files. Or even better use a cdn, that way you no longer need to worry about static assets.

The sample code is also failing: localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/assets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. I will try it with CDN, maybe that is the easiest way...
